# How to remove the ADD USER in the "admin users area" in Drupal 7

Tags: user-interface, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, symfony-cmf

I already did the **admin only register** but I would like to remove this tab if anyone can help me[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove this button from the current page or disallow a user role to add users? It is totally different.

Comment: Both ways will be appreciated  , I would like to just hide it since I have already  some other way for registering new users,  but also making this button just visible  to  ADMIN ROLE  is a great idea.   Altought I did the permission change before  but still it appears to a ROL I dont want to see this button.  Thanks for your reply !

Comment: The Administer user permission takes out even the page where you can see the users list, I want the ROL to admin and see them, but not to create them

Answer (score 0):

In admin menu, under People -> Permissions (/admin/people/permissions) you can set permissions for every user role. Under the "User" permissions group there is permission "Administer users". I believe that's the one you should disallow and this button won't appear for specific role.

You can also use CSS to hide that link, but it wouldn't be very clean way...but it's an option B.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this link is an Action Link which is a menu item. There are a lot of methods to hide it. Here are some suggestions.

1) On a **custom module** alter the menu that displays the link (with [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). The code to do this should be something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Check current user is not User 1 (admin)
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid !== "1") {
    // Disable the link of admin/people/create
    $items ['admin/people/create']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

More specific alters can be done with [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7) function. Also some modules may do this from a UI such as [Tab Tame](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer)r but haven't tried it.

2) Use the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module that **overrides** this view and remove the link from the views UI.

3) Use common [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to do the same as above. Notice that you have to create that page with the same url (admin/people)

4) There are some more complex solutions with permissions by role such as the module [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) but it may be too much for your simple case.